# Почему не всегда записывается дамп ядра?

Tags: linux, dump

На определённом хосте иногда падает один процесс, поэтому для него была включена запись дампов ядра. Один раз дамп записался, но с тех пор было ещё три падения — дампов нет.

```bash
$ cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep core | grep -v '#'
*    -    core    unlimited

$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/tmp/core.%e.%p.%h.%t

$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 2063246
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2063246
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

$ cat /proc/$(pgrep myprocess)/limits | grep core
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
```

Свободного места достаточно (около 17Gb, дамп занимает 2-4 Gb). Вручную процесс никто не останавливал. О том, что было именно падение, я сужу по логам:

monit:

```bash
[NOVT Feb 12 05:07:21] error    : 'myprocess' process is not running
[NOVT Feb 12 05:07:21] info     : 'myprocess' trying to restart
[NOVT Feb 12 05:07:21] info     : 'myprocess' start: /etc/init.d/myprocess
[NOVT Feb 12 05:09:21] info     : 'myprocess' process is running with pid 22233
```

nginx, который направляет запросы этому процессу (оставил только нужное). Видим, что в 05:06:20 уже вернул 502.

```bash
1.2.3.4 myhost - [12/Feb/2016:05:05:49 +0600] "POST someurl" 200 2659 ...
1.2.3.4 myhost - [12/Feb/2016:05:05:49 +0600] "POST someurl" 200 933 ...
1.2.3.4 myhost - [12/Feb/2016:05:06:20 +0600] "POST someurl" 502 166 ...
```

Я специально тестировал и убедился, что на точно такой же конфигурации дампы ядра пишутся, в том числе когда уже есть один дамп (использовал `kill -SIGSEGV pid`). UPD: протестировал прямо на этом хосте: дамп пишется.

В [документации](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core) перечислены возможные причины, но вроде бы никакие условия не меняются, так что и дампы должны записываться всегда или никогда.

Вопросы:

- Может ли процесс в linux как-то аварийно завершить работу, чтобы это не попало под условия, в которых не инициализируется дамп?
- В чём ещё может быть причина, куда копать, что исследовать?

Comment: Кстати, искал подходящую метку для настройки лимитов в linux, но не нашёл. Знаете — добавьте )

Comment: а как процесс запускается? может, прописать юлимит прямо в инит-скрипт?

Comment: @o2gy `cat /proc/$(pgrep myprocess)/limits | grep core` подтверждает, что уже работающий процесс имеет верные лимиты. Пока что мы тут копаем в сторону того, с каким кодом завершается процесс. Некоторые коды кроме `0` тоже не вызывают записи дампа. Когда раскопаем - напишу подробный ответ. )

Comment: точно, может там в процессе где-то тупо срабатывает return/exit :)
корки нету, вот и дампа нету.

Comment: в принципе, любой exit(0) лучше уничтожить к херам либо предусмотреть в дебаг-моде, чтобы это событие в логи попадало

Answer (score 1):

*Из комментария [@o2gy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179209/o2gy):*

Может там в процессе где-то срабатывает `return`/`exit`? Core dump нету, вот и итоговый дамп не создаётся.